# What does a "Synchronous" type detail mean in dmidecode?

Tags: linux, memory, hardware, dmidecode

I'm curious if my 2 DIMMs are running dual-channel or not and use:

```
dmidecode -t 17
```

> ...
>   Type Detail: Synchronous
>   ...

What does a "Synchronous" type detail mean? Dual-channel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the RAM sticks are driven by a clock signal — as opposed to (older) asynchronous DRAMs. See [the Wikipedia page on SDRAMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronous_dynamic_random-access_memory).

To find out whether your RAM is dual-channel, look for “Interleaved Data Depth” in dmidecode output. It should say 1 for single and 2 for dual channel RAM.